# Objective-C iOS - UIWebView: how ignoring cached data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uiwebview

I've tried more methods to load a request in UIWebView without using of cached data. I've to load a **protected pdf** from url. Unfortunately any attempt was unsuccessful. Here my code:

```
           [mypdfView removeFromSuperview];
            mypdfView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,85,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-150)];
            mypdfView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            mypdfView .autoresizesSubviews = YES;
            mypdfView .autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);

            NSString *urlstring = @"https://user:psw@mysites.com/mypdf.pdf";
            NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
            NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];
           [mypdfView  loadRequest:myRequest];
```

First try: new request ignoring cached data

```
NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0];
```

No successful.
Second try: clean myRequest cached data

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:myRequest];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

No way. 3 try: clean all cache and remove all cookie

```
                [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache]removeAllCachedResponses];
                [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
                [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
 for(NSHTTPCookie *cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) {

                    if([[cookie domain] isEqualToString:urlstring]) {

                        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
                    }
                }
```

Again. No success. So tried to remove all credentials:

```
NSURLCredentialStorage *credentialsStorage = [NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage];
                NSDictionary *allCredentials = [credentialsStorage allCredentials];
                for (NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace in allCredentials) {
                    NSDictionary *credentials = [credentialsStorage credentialsForProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];
                    for (NSString *credentialKey in credentials) {
                        [credentialsStorage removeCredential:[credentials objectForKey:credentialKey] forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];
                    }
                }
```

Again unsuccessful.

Any ideas?

Thanks for yours help.

Comment: How do you know that file is being loaded from cache?

Comment: ‘Cause I changed it then reloaded webview And not change in webview.

Comment: More I removed it from my server And webview stil display it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using WKWebView instead of UIWebView? I would recommend that as UIWebView has been deprecated for quite some time now. For WKWebView, you could do the following

```
 WKWebsiteDataStore *dateStore = [WKWebsiteDataStore defaultDataStore];
 [dateStore fetchDataRecordsOfTypes:[WKWebsiteDataStore allWebsiteDataTypes] completionHandler:^(NSArray<WKWebsiteDataRecord *> * __nonnull records) {

                                                                             for (WKWebsiteDataRecord *record  in records) {

                                                                                 [[WKWebsiteDataStore defaultDataStore] removeDataOfTypes:record.dataTypes
                                                                                                                           forDataRecords:@[record]
                                                                                                                        completionHandler:^{

                                                                                                                            NSLog(@"Record Cleared: %@", record.displayName);

                                                                                                                        }];

                                                                             }

                                                                         }];
```

In any case, I would modify the cache policy]of the [NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest?language=objc) object you are using before loading it up in the web view. I think you're gonna wanna set that to `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` before sending the -loadRequest message to your web view instance, but you might want to look at the [NSURLRequestCachePolicy documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequestcachepolicy?language=objc) to see all the available options and their respective behaviors.

Comment: I've solved simply create every times a new pdf file with different name. But next time I'll use WKWebView! Thanks
(I have set NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData before sending load request.)